# printing users rows on webpage using node.js and my sql

Tags: node.js

I working on a code to printing users email row on webpage if users have a certain value on some row using node.js and my sql

so I created this code
I get the right values when I run it on console.log 
but when I tried it with 
res.send();
I get this error

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

and just get one row not all users rows

I tried to write return after my res.send 
and that's give me only one row how I can get all row on the webpage ?

```
app.get('/usersrooms', function (req, res, next) {
    var userslist = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";    
    var query = connection.query(userslist, function(err,rows, result) {

    if (rows.length > 0) {
        for (var i in rows) {


            if (rows[i].onmatch == 0){
                //console.log("the mails",rows[i].email);

                res.send('hello',rows[i].email)

            }


        }
    }

    })

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error` you got because, you are sending the response even before the for **loop is completed**,

**The solution is:**

Take an array **`rows_array = []`**

Push the email from the loop into that array,

**`rows_array.push(rows[i].email)`**

After the loop completes, send that array as a response,

**`res.send('hello',rows_array)`**

```
app.get('/usersrooms', function (req, res, next) {
    var userslist = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";    
    var query = connection.query(userslist, function(err,rows, result) {

    if (rows.length > 0) {
        var rows_array = []
        for (var i in rows) {


            if (rows[i].onmatch == 0){
                //console.log("the mails",rows[i].email);
                rows_array.push(rows[i].email)


            }


        }
        res.send('hello',rows_array)
    }

    })

});
```

Comment: can i use onclick with the output of array ?

Comment: onclick, in the front-end?

Comment: you can use `onclick` in the front end, I dont know what  you are using, you can just loop the response and use on-click in `HTML`.. unfortunately I am leaving for the day.. will help you once I come back tomorrow

Comment: with every email like that on php if row['test'] == 0 {
      ?>
      <span class="UserNameS" onclick="parent.location='redirect.php?id=<?php echo $token;?>&name=<?php echo $name;?>';"> <?php echo $name;?>
      </span>
      <?php
      
     }